# Android webview load java script function in xhtml

Tags: javascript, android, webview, xhtml

I use loadUrl function to call a JavaScript function inside my webview:

```
 webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){
 if (window.find) {
  if(window.getSelection){
 window.document.designMode = 'on';
  window.document.execCommand('hiliteColor',false,'yellow');
 window.document.designMode = 'off';
  }}})()");
```

this for heightlight selected text
it is working good with me during load html files to my webview but it did not work when trying to view xhtml files to webview how can i handle this pls?

Comment: Hi @user3764397, can you put the xhtml code you use for viewing within the webview?

Comment: @AmmarCSE i can not understand what do you mean by xhtml code it is a normal web page with xhtml extension.